# Visio automation via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, visio

I have a script that automates the a Visio diagram, i based my script on the official Office site: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/f77fb025-11ee-48f3-8409-9bb567a63fc3

Well to be honest i have no idea how to retrieve the values of the "shape data", this shape data is for example (Serial number, Building, Location, etc...) from the pc stencil.
I want to add and revise this values programatically, i ve checked the object model reference but without luck.

Can someone help me?

here is the code, it opens a visio document and adds a pc stencil to the drawing.

```
$application = New-Object -ComObject Visio.Application
$application.visible = $true
$documents = $application.Documents
$document = $documents.Add("Basic Network Diagram.vst")
$pages = $application.ActiveDocument.Pages
$page = $pages.Item(1)


$ComputerStencil = $application.Documents.Add("Computers and Monitors.vss")



$pc = $ComputerStencil.Masters.Item("PC")
$shape1 = $page.Drop($pc, 2.2, 6.8)
$shape1.Text = "Some text...."
```

Thanxs for your time!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Visio Automation library](https://github.com/saveenr/VisioAutomation) may help you:

Here's an example of how you can use it in C#. Using it in PowerShell should not be difficult.

```
var app = new IVisio.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Add("");
var page = doc.Pages[1];
var shape1 = page.DrawRectangle(1, 1, 3, 4);
VisioAutomation.CustomProperties.CustomPropertyHelper.Set(shape1,"Hello","World");
var props = VisioAutomation.CustomProperties.CustomPropertyHelper.Get(shape1);
```

Using the [Visio PowerShell Module](https://github.com/saveenr/VisioPowerShell), the code will look something like this:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Import-Module Visio

$app= New-VisioApplication
$doc = New-VisioDocument
$stencil_net = Open-VisioDocument "Basic Network Diagram.vst"
$stencil_comp = Open-VisioDocument "Computers and Monitors.vss"


$pc_master = Get-VisioMaster "PC" $stencil_comp 
$shapes = New-VisioShape -Masters $pc_master -Points 2.2,6.8
Set-VisioText "Some Text..."
Set-VisioCustomProperty -Name "prop1" -Value "val1"
Set-VisioCustomProperty -Name "prop2" -Value "val2"


$shapedata_col = Get-VisioCustomProperty -Shapes $shapes 
foreach ($shapedata in $shapedata_col)
{
    Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
    Write-Host Name $shapedata.Name
    Write-Host Type $shapedata.Type
    Write-Host Value $shapedata.Value
    Write-Host Prompt $shapedata.Prompt
    Write-Host Ask $shapedata.Ask
    Write-Host Calendar $shapedata.Calendar
    Write-Host Format $shapedata.Format
    Write-Host Invisible $shapedata.Invisible
    Write-Host Label $shapedata.Label
    Write-Host LangId $shapedata.LangId
    Write-Host ShapeID $shapedata.ShapeID
    Write-Host SortKey $shapedata.SortKey
}
```

At the bottom you can see how to set and retrieve shape data.

Comment: Thanks alot!! at the beginning I was getting some errors while importing the VisioPS module, then upgraded to powershell 3.0 and solved the issue. Now I'm able to set the values, but i am not able to get the actual value, read the documentation [link](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=1ff099edb1c7ebfa&id=1FF099EDB1C7EBFA!37017&authkey=!AC3a8aNj0Lc8318#!/view.aspx?cid=1FF099EDB1C7EBFA&resid=1FF099EDB1C7EBFA!1407&app=Word&authkey=!AC3a8aNj0Lc8318) but the output of Get-VisioCustomProperty is totally different. here is the output

Comment: `PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE> $shapedata.get_Values()

KeyValue                                                            
--- ----                                                            
Manufacturer                                          VisioAutomation.CustomProperties.CustomPropertyCells             `

Comment: I'll update the documentation shortly.

In summary: Get-VisioCustomProperty cmdlet returns a dictionary mapping shape-object -> a dictionary of the properties in that shape.

This secondary dictionary is a simple string -> custom property cells mapping

Comment: I cant access this dictionary, dont know what im doing wrong.... Can you please help me? I set the values already but i cant parse them...

Comment: My goal is just to know programatically the values contained in "Manufacturer" or in this case "prop1", it sounds soo easy but I am going crazy here!! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueValdés - I've updated the sample code above. It should be clear how to get the value now. By the way, I uploaded a new version of VisioPS last week so you should use that version.

Comment: @saveenr- Thank you very much!! Now i'm able to continue with the rest of my code!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also export the drawing as html, then parse the resulting data.xml.